# Azure Functions Swashbuckle: Failed to resolve assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' during rebuild

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, swagger, swashbuckle

I want to add OpenAPI specification to my Azure Functions app. For that I wanted to use [AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle) since it can auto generate the specification and display it via swagger-ui.

When I first install the package via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle) everything works fine. The specification is generated automatically, and I can view it through the swagger-ui.

As soon as I rebuild my project / solution, it doesn't build anymore. The following error message is prompted during the build:

```
3>C:\Users\Agent1\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\3.0.13\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): Error  : Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at MakeFunctionJson.AttributeExtensions.IsWebJobsAttribute(CustomAttribute attribute)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.<>c.<ToFunctionJsonBindings>b__1_0(CustomAttribute a)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.ToFunctionJsonBindings(ParameterDefinition parameterInfo)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.<>c.<ToFunctionJson>b__6_1(ParameterDefinition p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.ToFunctionJson(MethodDefinition method, String assemblyPath)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.GenerateFunctions(IEnumerable`1 types)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
Error generating functions metadata
```

I'm using AzureFunctions V3 with .NET Core 3.1.

This is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    <OutputPath>../../dist/apps/api</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle" Version="3.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="CSharpFunctionalExtensions" Version="2.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.0.0-beta.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.17">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Scriban" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I already deleted my local .nuget directory, cleaned nuget cache and updated other packages but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added `[FromQuery]` or any other attribute to your azure function "controller signature" it could happened.
You can try to remove the `[FromQuery]` attribute.

You can refer this on-going github [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/435) about the same problem.

Comment: Ah I had a `[FromBody]` attribute set in one of my functions. I only searched for `[FromQuery]`. Now everything works fine. Thanks.